# Android Studio - "Cannot Resolve onCreate as a method", same for setContentView, getMenuInflater and onOptionsItemSelected

Tags: android-studio

I am making a splash screen for my app and I am following this tutorial: [Android Programming Tutorial - 4 - Adding a Splash Screen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YVHnqv9ouAM). But for some reason, when I create the splash screen activity, it throws errors!

```
package com.haziqhussain.hazgames;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class SplashScreen {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.splash_screen, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Everything seems normal however some code is not having it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to extend the `ActionBarActivity` class. The `ActionBarActivity` contains the methods which you are trying to override.

Comment: You should read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Answer (score 1):

Need not necessarily be **ActionBarActivity**. Whenever your class is using the life cycle states of an **Activity**(OnCreate(), OnStart(), OnPause, etc.)you have to extend **Activity** because all of the activity classes are subclasses of android.app.Activity.